# Compute Sum of Logarithms Efficiently

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation, numerical-methods

For an embedded software implementation I would like to compute,

$S(b) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}log( x_i - b )$,

for various values of $b$. Here $x_i$ is an array of fixed numbers.

Is there a fast way to do this without having to recompute the sum?

--

I tried looking at the Taylor expansion of $log( x - b )$ around $x=a$

$log( x - b ) \approx log(a-b) + \frac{x-a}{a-b} - \frac{(x-a)^2}{2(a-b)^2} + \frac{(x-a)^3}{3(a-b)^3} - \frac{(x-a)^4}{4(a-b)^4} + O((x-a)^5)$.

Hence,

$S(b) \approx \sum_{i=1}^N log(a-b) + \frac{x_i-a}{a-b} - \frac{(x_i-a)^2}{2(a-b)^2} + \frac{(x_i-a)^3}{3(a-b)^3} - \frac{(x_i-a)^4}{4(a-b)^4} + O((x_i-a)^5)$.

Then in $S(b)$ all sums that depend on $x_i$ can be precomputed.

However, I have my doubts about the accuracy of this approach.

Comment: If $b$ is one of the $x_i,$ as stated, then don't you get $\log(b - b)$ as one of your terms? This produces an undefined result.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You say for various values of $b$, but from the next line we understand that $b$ is fixed. And what's more, one of the arguments of the logs is guaranteed to be zero !

Comment: Given the $x_i$ divide the real line (or the plane, or space) into intervals (boxes) of a size certain size (you need to judge the seize). Then given $b$, look at the interval in which it falls. For the $x_i$ inside that interval, just compute $\log$. For the $x_i$ outside the box compute the Taylor, yes, but the Taylor expansion at infinity and sum. Those sums of Taylor expansions at infinity can be precomputed for each box (their coefficients).

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for your comment. I removed the line in my post where I state b is fixed.

Comment: Your formula for $S(b)$ is missing the $b^k$ factors.

Comment: Fixed or floating-point ?

Comment: Your formula for $S(b)$ is missing the $b^k$ factors, and it is not a good idea to introduce a (inaccurate) series while you still require the evaluation of a logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $a_i$ is real and $a_i \neq 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N,$ then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \log(a_i) = \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^N a_i \right).
$$

I suspect, however, that this defeats your purpose for using logarithms in the first place.
(The last time I recall taking a sum of many logarithms, it was to avoid floating-point overflow while computing products of many terms in a computer program.)

If the purpose of the logarithms is what I suspect, perhaps you should take one step back and tell us the *real* reason why you want to do this calculation. Perhaps there's a completely different way to do what you want without even mentioning logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the logarithm out of the sum and you get the logarithm of the product, which is a polynomial.

- you can't avoid the evaluation of the logarithm, which you can implement with the series for $\log\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$, after bringing the argument in the range $[\frac12,2)$, or with the CORDIC algorithm.
- you can't avoid the evaluation of the polynomial in $b$, which takes $n$ subtractions and $n-1$ products in the current setting. (Precomputation of the expanded form and use of the Horner scheme will not really help.)
- if you face overflow issues with the product, you can bring the factors closer to $1$ by factoring out a suitable power of a constant, say $2$, which you compensate later by accounting for the sum of these powers.